# Load Operation failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When we create a new project or open some project in visual studio mac 2019(Version 8.6.8) then it shows two errors:

1. Load Operation Failed.
2. Could not load project "project directory".

Comment: Does it work in older version ? You could  send the feedback : **Help -> Report a problem** .

Comment: changed directory from desktop to download problem solved